# Does a composite server control(inc. user control, custom server control) normally encapsulate css properties?

Tags: asp.net, css

If a composite server control normally encapsulate styling information inside, it is an example of code encapsulation and modularization. However if css properties are included inside the composite control, it is not ideal for code/styling separation and css code re-use principles. Now which consideration should be the main consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by giving my custom control a very plain, generic look - possibly leaving the out-of-the-box look as is. Add CSS style attributes to the various elements in the control and expose them as properties. That is, expose the CSS rules as name/value properties that can be set.

If your control relies on some basic images, CSS, etc. you can use an embedded resource:

http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/09/26/how-to-embedded-stylesheet-file-with-custom-control.aspx

You have to think in terms of reuse and making this as simple as possible for the person using the control.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into ASP.NET theming?  One explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh(v=VS.100).aspx.  While, unfortunately, I have not had a chance to use theming, I understand it is a canonical way to approach this issue.

You will probably need to have style information in your control so that it renders properly without a theme, but the theme can override the styles in the control.

Otherwise, you could define classes for whatever is needed in the control so that they can be styled more easily with CSS, but any default styles you would put in the control itself could override the CSS.  If you really wanted to go down that path, you might come up with a mechanism to put CSS in the header that could be overridden by any otherwise-specified CSS in the page.  However, this is kind of reinventing the wheel, since theming can take care of this kind of thing.